# How to constantly check div for class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It works once when you click on the area to check if it has "top-nav", but how do I make it continually check so that the alerts work every time it doesn't, or has the class "top-nav"

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/117mg0y1/

```js
 if(!$('.view-projects').hasClass("top-nav")){
 alert('has');

 }else if($('.view-projects').hasClass("top-nav")){
  alert('hey');
   
 }
 
 $('.push').click(function(){
 $('.view-projects').toggleClass('top-nav');
 });
```

```css
.view-projects{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background:black;
}
body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.push{
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-projects"></div>

<div class="push"></div>
```

Comment: You mean you want on click? like: https://jsfiddle.net/117mg0y1/1/

Comment: Mutation Observers for everything moderns (in other words, NOT IE10 or earlier) - mutation EVENTS for IE10 and buggy in IE9

Comment: @JaromandaX, If click handher is the only source to change the `class`, why do we introduce `Mutation Observers` ?

Comment: true, I didn't read the code very well at all :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. Hope it helps!

```
$('.push').click(function(){
    //toggle the class 'top-nav' for element with class='view-projects'
    $('.view-projects').toggleClass('top-nav');
    //checks if our element/tag has class='top-nav'
    if($('.view-projects').hasClass("top-nav")){
        console.info("Our div has class='top-nave'");//this will print data in console in blue color instead of the old school alert
    }else{ //Else your div don't have the required class
        console.info("Our div does not have class='top-nave'"); //this will print data in console in blue color instead of the old school alert  
    }
});
```

Comment: I will post an answer for same with description @RayonDabre

Comment: @RayonDabre the description is very simple. First we need the click event for clicking functionality, then I'm using the toggleClass event to toggle the 'top-nav' class to the selector ('.view-projects') , finally I'm just using the if statement to check if the selector has the specific class or not. Thar is all :)

Comment: Unfortunately OP would no understand this by going through answer otherwise he would have made out on his own..Better to edit the answer with above description/explanation..

Comment: @xpng I have suggested an edit and changed the conditions for if() {} else

Comment: @shivgre and RayonDabre I accepted your comments on my code. Thanks for the input mates :)!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to do two things when you click on the ".push" element:

1. toggle the class of ".view-projects" with "top-nav" and...
2. alert if ".view-projects" has or does not have this class.

That said, there's no need to constantly check with an interval. Since both of those situation depend on the click handler... use the click handler :)

```
$('.push').click(function(){
    // First toggle the class
    $('.view-projects').toggleClass('top-nav');

    // Now do the alert based on what the current class is
    var hasTopNav = $('.view-projects').hasClass('top-nav'); // returns true or false
    if ( hasTopNav ) {
        alert("has");
    } else {
        alert("hey");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.is()` with parameter `".top-nav"` chained to `.toggleClass()` within `click` handler. Note, following logic at Question, `"hey"` is alerted when element does have `top-nav` `className`, `"has"` is alerted when `.view-projects` does not have `top-nav` `className`

```
 $(".push").click(function(){
   alert($(".view-projects").toggleClass("top-nav").is(".top-nav") ? "hey" : "has")
 });
```

```js
if(!$('.view-projects').hasClass("top-nav")){
 alert('has');

 }else if($('.view-projects').hasClass("top-nav")){
  alert('hey');
   
 }
 
 $(".push").click(function(){
   alert($('.view-projects').toggleClass("top-nav").is(".top-nav")? "hey" : "has");
 });
```

```css
.view-projects{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background:black;
}
body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.push{
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-projects"></div>

<div class="push"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
 if(!$('.view-projects').hasClass("top-nav")){
 alert('has');

 }else if($('.view-projects').hasClass("top-nav")){
  alert('hey');
   
 }
 
 $('.push').click(function(){
 $('.view-projects').toggleClass('top-nav');
  if(!$('.view-projects').hasClass("top-nav")){
 alert('has');

 }else if($('.view-projects').hasClass("top-nav")){
  alert('hey');
   
 }
 });
```

```css
.view-projects{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background:black;
}
body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.push{
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-projects"></div>

<div class="push"></div>
```